# Distribution of sum of inverses with random signs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, martingales, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(Z_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{P}(Z_i=1)=\mathbb{P}(Z_i=-1)=1/2$. Define $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nZ_k/k$. Since $(S_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a martingale that is bounded in $L^p$ for $p>1$, it converges a.s. and in $L^p$ to some r.v. $S_\infty$.

Can we determine the distribution of $S_\infty$?

Comment: Well, the even moments $<S^{2j}_\infty>$ are $\zeta(2j)$, since $<S^{2j}_\infty>=\sum_k{<Z^{2j}> \over k^{2j}}$

Comment: @user619894 We can find the characteristic function which is $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\cos(\xi/n)$. It seems that $S_\infty$ has a density but I'm not sure it can be expressed in terms of usual functions

Comment: The moments are finite, doesn't that imply that the PDF exists?

Comment: I'm not sure I see which property you're referring to? One other way to do things is to say that the characteristic function is integrable so $S_\infty$ has a density. I would like to know how to write this density but I'm not able to find anything conclusive

Comment: Here is a [AMM article about this distribution](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3647827?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents), preprint [here](http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/people/schmu/publications.html) (click on "random harmonic series").

Comment: @MikeEarnest great! You can post this as an answer if you'd like and I will accept it